# SQLIte from .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, frameworks

My question is how to get SQLite working under .NET framework, v 4.7+, period and where the location of the DB changes with each customer site I install at?

Issue:

My problem with SQLite in .NET framework is I keep getting DLL for SQLite not found or DB factory missing. After spending 3-4 days perusing the i-net and trying different things suggested I've not found a resolve.  Maybe I'm that 5-pound hammer is a glass factory 8).

Here's the background:

Requirement is Caller/Host is VBA application, the called "dll" must adhere to COM interface functionality.

I've built a .NET COM exposed DLL that accesses data from a DB using .NET framework 4.7.2, EF 6.4.4 and DBMS SQL Express 2019 which works fine. Challenge is customer IT depts acceptance of solution.

There are 2 DBs, one DB is a read many, write none with 7 tables, one table has 950,000+ rows. The other DB has 2 tables both read many, write occasionally. Both DBs are shared by multiple workstations.

The goal is to replace SQL Express with SQLite. Reason: SQLite is self-contained with no IT involvement to install, except to grant install rights in the first place 8).

Tried XML/Json source file with memory dataset, performance was slow on load, 10-30 seconds, and ran into "out of memory" errors testing with minimal PC spec I find customers using.

Found I can do the data access using .NET 5 or 6 with EF core. I can pass the location of the DB file(s) as required (the DB will be in a folder local or even on a server file share different than my DLL). This took less than a day to get working. The rub here is that .NET framework cannot call .NET DLLs in my testing.

In .NET 6 I call the Class Library as follows:

```
PostalDataLib tstDB = new(sysDBFQN, custDBFQN);
```

The Constructor looks like this:

```
public PostalDataLib(string sysDbFQN, string cusDbFQN)
    {
      if (!File.Exists(sysDbFQN)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid FQN, file not found", nameof(sysDbFQN));
      if (!File.Exists(cusDbFQN)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid FQN, file not found", nameof(cusDbFQN));
      _custFQN = cusDbFQN;
      _sysFQN = sysDbFQN;
      _optsPostalData = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PostalDB>().UseSqlite($"Data Source={sysDbFQN}").Options;
      _optsCustData = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PostalCustDB>().UseSqlite($"Data Source={cusDbFQN}").Options;
    }
```

I then open the DB(s) as follows:

```
using PostalDB dbctx = new(_optsPostalData);
using PostalCustDB dbctxcus = new(_optsCustData);
```

But I can't seem to make this workable under .NET framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework and SQLite, the ultimate how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494481/entity-framework-and-sqlite-the-ultimate-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this.

I've moved the Data access layer into two parts.  A tcp Server and the main VBA facing DLL as a TCP client using synchronous methods.  This allows for 1 Data access point (added benefit) from multiple PCs. The server side is written using .Net 6.0.  The client is written using .Net framework 4.7.2. Using Json payloads as messaging.  The TCP elements are using WatsonTCP. Had to use sources not NUget package in the Client to address newtonsoft.Json version issues. By launching the server as a windows scheduler task I get the silent running like a windows service but as I found out without the issue of not finding the appsettings.json file.

The bottom line is it seems that there is no clear information being offered on how to make SQLIte dynamically point to DB via a config file FQN in .net framework 4.7. (not the same as does not support)